# SQL Server: UDT versus UDDT?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlclr, user-defined-types, user-defined-data-types

What's the difference between User-Defined Types (UDT) and User-Defined Data Types (UDDT)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**User-Defined Data Types (UDDT)** are simple aliases, in pure T-SQL, based on the "native" types that come with SQL Server (i.e. all except the CLR types of Geography, Geometry, and Hierarchy). These are for convenience in allowing for consistency in data models, the idea being that you avoid having the same "property" across tables defined in different ways.

An example of a UDDT is defining `SSN` to be a `CHAR(11)`. Or maybe `ClientID` would be `INT`.

**User-Defined Types (UDT)** are "complex" types written in SQLCLR (i.e. NET / CLR Integration) and are whatever you create them to be. They are what the Geography, Geometry, and Hierarchy types are based on. Their direct representation is VARBINARY, but you don't interact with them directly (not usually). Like those 3 CLR types and the XML datatype, you interact with UDTs via methods and properties that are defined in them. They can have both static and instance based methods and properties. You can even override the operators by which they are compared so that you can do special handling when used in the context of `=`, `<`, or whatever you decide to override.

An example can be an Array / Collection. You store a collection internally, and expose methods for `.Add()`, `.GetByIndex()`, etc. You can expose properties such as `.Length`, etc. So you would declare it like:

```
DECLARE @VarName SchemaName.TypeName;
```

You can update it through properties and methods:

```
SET @VarName = @VarName.Method(@var1, 'LiteralValue');
```

You can get values out of it through properties and methods:

```
SELECT @VarName.AnotherMethod(), @VarName.SomeProperty;
```

If you want examples that show some of these variations and that you can even play with, you can download the Free version of [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_35495291) library (which I wrote, but the Types are free) which comes with three UDTs, one of which is **Type_HashTable** that has some good examples in the manual. You can find the info for **Type_HashTable** starting on page 178 of the manual (page 186 in the PDF).

Comment: There's also [User Defined Table Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql), which are required for using table-valued parameters (but not table-valued variables): `CREATE TYPE [name] AS TABLE ( ... )`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer educated me, but this is how i explain UDT vs UDDT to the uninitiated:

UDDT is customizing basic types into "new" types (note that in the example below, only length differs between CONTACTNAME and EMAILADDRESS).

```
CREATE TYPE CONTACTNAME FROM NVARCHAR(130) NOT NULL
CREATE TYPE EMAILADDRESS FROM NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
CREATE TYPE BIRTHDAY FROM DATE NULL
CREATE TYPE BIRTHTIME FROM DATETIME NULL
```

UDT is a "data structure", created as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.contactInformation
AS TABLE
(
  FileID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
  [Name] CONTACTNAME,
  [FirstName] NVARCHAR(20),
  [EMail] EMAILADDRESS
);
GO
```

In my experience,
UDDT can improve readability, as well as enforce standards.
UDT can be applied in apps running on Entity Framework to improve performance between the app and the server by providing bulk transfer (as opposed to row-by-row transfers).

Comment: "UDT can be applied in apps running on Entity Framework to improve performance between the app and the server by providing bulk transfer (as opposed to row-by-row transfers)." - While Entity Framework (and EF Core) _does_ support UDTs for table-valued-parameters, it effectively inherits it from the lower-level ADO.NET layer (which also supports UDTs), in fact EF's support for UDTs is kinda limited and (to my knowledge) you can't bind a UDT to actual Entity Types either (as a UDT is invariably a _subset_ of the entity's table design, e.g. without computed columns, temporal-table columns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[UDTs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131064(v=sql.110).aspx) (User Defined Type): UDTs can be used in the definition of database objects, as variables in Transact-SQL batches, in functions and stored procedures, and as arguments in functions and stored procedures.

[UDDTs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933121(v=sql.80).aspx) (User Defined Data Type): User-defined data types can be used when several tables must store the same type of data in a column and you must ensure that these columns have exactly the same data type, length, and nullability. For example, a user-defined data type called postal_code could be created based on the char data type.

Comment: I understand that UDDTs are essentially aliases for full SQL type specs, but I'm not quite getting what UDTs are.  Any chance you could add an example?  The MSDN page isn't particularly helpful in this case.

Comment: UDTs are created in .NET Framework, then after registering the assembly with MS SQL we can use these types as if these were normal data types, e.g: `CREATE TABLE table (colName udtType);` May be this resource would be helpful: [CLR User-Defined Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131120(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

These are the same concept with two different names. AFAIK, UDT is in used since SQL 2005 and UDDT goes back to SQL 2000

Comment: They're definitely not the same.  One's an alias and the other's... something else, but I don't know what.